# Should I put an appositive comma around a possessive appositive

Tags: commas, possessives, appositives

In the process of editing a translation, I came across this sentence: "[That night] was also the opening curtain to the *Sheng Yuan* Emperor, Li Yi’s unification of the world." (To clarify *Sheng Yuan* Emperor is Li Yi's era name (the original work is in Chinese and is set in a fantasy version of China), and "opening curtain" is not a reference to an actual play)

I'm uncertain as to whether or not I should put an appositive comma after Li Yi. I've seen cases like this handled both ways, but I'd like to be as correct as possible.

(This is also a translation, not an original work, so I can't really add or remove anything significant, just move stuff around.)

Comment: Maybe you can say: [That night] was also the opening curtain to the play *Sheng Yuan*, depicting Emperor Li Yi’s unification of the world. Why divide the word Emperor from the emperor's name? I don't see the appositive.

Comment: "Possessive appositives" are strange. A possessive noun functions as an adjective, so how could *Li Yi's* — which modifies *unification* — be an appositive for the noun *emperor*? Nevertheless, with nonrestrictive possessive appositives, [some styles](https://bit.ly/3vnYYAz) suggest dropping the second comma: *[That night] was also the opening curtain to the Sheng Yuan Emperor, Li Yi’s unification of the world.* If Li Yi is the only Sheng Yuan Emperor, then no commas and no problem: *[That night] was also the opening curtain to Sheng Yuan Emperor Li Yi’s unification of the world.*

Comment: If the appositive is a restrictive one, then no commas are required, but if it's non-restrictive then it should be set apart with punctuation such as commas. Note that restrictive appositives are modifiers while non-restrictive one are supplements.